# Can't explain "crash" entries in output of the 'last' command

Tags: rhel, last

Last shows "crash" at 12:02 and 14:18, but the system didn't stop working at that time. The reboot at 15:03, on the other hand, was to recover from an actual crash - our system stopped responding at 14:46. Why does last show two "crashes" prior to the actual crash of the machine?

```
[admin@devbox log]$ last | head
myuser pts/2        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 15:12   still logged in
myuser pts/2        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 15:09 - 15:12  (00:02)
myuser pts/2        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 15:07 - 15:09  (00:01)
myuser pts/1        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 15:06   still logged in
myuser pts/0        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 15:04   still logged in
reboot   system boot  2.6.18-274.el5PA Wed Sep 28 15:03          (00:09)
myuser pts/1        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 14:18 - crash  (00:44)
myuser pts/0        myhostname  Wed Sep 28 12:02 - crash  (03:01)
```

EDIT: The reboot at 15:03 is real enough - but the two "crash" entries at 14:18 and 12:02 I can't explain.

Comment: 40 minutes ... but that's since the reboot.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't understand your question. When you said "but the system didn't reboot", I thought you were saying that no reboot happened at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`last` prints `crash` as the logout time when there is no logout entry in the [`wtmp`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/wtmp.5.en) database for a user session.

The last entry in `last` output means that `myuser` logged in on `pts/0` at 12:02 and, when the system crashed between 14:18 and 15:03, that user should be still logged in.

Usually, in `wtmp` there are two entries for each user session. One for the login time and one for the logout time. When a system crashes, the second entry could be missing. So `last` supposes that the user was still logged on when the system crashed and prints `crash` as the logout time.

To be clearer, that two "crash" lines are only the two session that were active when the system crashed around 15:00, not two *system crashes*.

Comment: Don't I feel rusty now... sure I knew this at some point! Thanks...

Comment: Does `last` always print a reboot record after a crash? And is it possible for the user session to crash but the entire OS?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is. `wtmp` will record each system boot but the message displayed (by `last`) is implementation dependent. 2) No, user session cannot _crash_. A program managing a user session can _abnormally end_ but, in this case, `wtmp` will simply record a _logout_.