# last - user reboot - logged-in period

Tags: system-recovery, last

I have the following lines extracted from the output of `last`. It shows two reboots, and that `userA` was logged in [right up to the reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21646/cant-explain-crash-entries-in-output-of-the-last-command). So far, I am able to interpret the data.

However, what I do not understand right now, is the login-time of the pseudo user `reboot`. For any ordinary users, the two times are the time the user logged-in and logged-out. In case, of a reboot, the entry for the log-out time is `crash`, indicating, that the user was logged-in right until the bitter end. No statement, whether the user is a victim or the culprit.

My guess is, that the log-in time of the pseudo user `reboot` is the time when the system reboot was initiated. However, what determines the log-out time of the user `reboot`?

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.13.1. Mon Nov 28 08:08 - 10:35  (02:26)    
userA    pts/0        10.ZZ.YY.XX      Sun Nov 27 08:01 - crash (1+00:06)   
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.13.1. Sun Nov 27 07:36 - 10:35 (1+02:58)   
userA    pts/9        10.ZZ.YY.XX      Fri Nov 25 17:39 - crash (1+13:57)   
userA    pts/0        10.ZZ.YY.XX      Fri Nov 25 16:17 - crash (1+15:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its refer to the time between reboots. i will explain with example:

```
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 10:53   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.11.1. Mon Nov 28 10:14 - 11:00  (00:45)    
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 10:11 - down   (00:02)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.11.1. Mon Nov 28 10:09 - 10:14  (00:04)    
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 10:08 - down   (00:01)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.11.1. Mon Nov 28 10:07 - 10:09  (00:01)    
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 10:06 - down   (00:01)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.11.1. Mon Nov 28 10:05 - 10:07  (00:01)    
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 09:23 - down   (00:41)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.11.1. Mon Nov 28 09:21 - 10:05  (00:43)    
root     pts/0        192.168.10.58    Mon Nov 28 04:42 - down   (04:39)
```

the last reboot logout time will keep change every minute and you can notice that if you type `last` any time you will see that the last reboot has the present time and the reboots before it every each one of them refer to the time that next reboot happen

Answer (score 1):

There is no user account named `reboot`. From `man last`:

> The  pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.  Thus `last reboot` will show a log of all the reboots since the log  file  was created.

Comment: I know, my question was  not on why there is a user listed named `reboot`, but how the log-out time of `reboot` is determined.

Comment: @DohnJoe - in the case of the `crash` entry, it seems that's listed when, for whatever reason, a second logout time is not recorded in `wtmp`. Seems like it could be because of a system crash, or anything else that might cause `wtmp` to not get written to. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21661/12916

Comment: @DohnJoe - in normal logout situations, the logout time is the current `hh:mm` of the logout, then the delta `(days+hh:mm)` is shown on the far right.

I know this question/answer is old, but I hope this helps - I was just wondering the same thing.